# How to transform array of objects into one object by Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arraylist, lodash

Example from this:

```
[
    {"name":"tony", "age":14},
    {"name":"jacky", "age":23},
    {"name":"lucy", "age":34},
    {"name":"sam", "age":15},
    {"name":"jay", "age":31}
]
```

to:

```
{
    "tony": [],
    "jacky": [],
    "lucy": [],
    "sam": [],
    "jay": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer not to use `for` or `reduce`, here's a lodash one-liner

```
_(data).keyBy('name').mapValues(() => []).value()
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use `Lodash`. [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) will do the job.

```js
const data = [
    {"name":"tony", "age":14},
    {"name":"jacky", "age":23},
    {"name":"lucy", "age":34},
    {"name":"sam", "age":15},
    {"name":"jay", "age":31}
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = [];
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function .

```js
var arr =[ {"name":"tony", "age":14}, {"name":"jacky", "age":23}, {"name":"lucy", "age":34}, {"name":"sam", "age":15}, {"name":"jay", "age":31} ]
var obj={}

arr.forEach(function(a){
 obj[a.name]=[]
})
console.log(obj)
```

**Or** simple do with [`Array#reduce`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)

```js
var arr =[ {"name":"tony", "age":14}, {"name":"jacky", "age":23}, {"name":"lucy", "age":34}, {"name":"sam", "age":15}, {"name":"jay", "age":31} ]

var res = arr.reduce((a,b) => (a[b.name]=[] ,a),{})
console.log(res)
```